# How to display user Cover photo in Facebook as the image for UIImageView in iOS

Tags: ios, uiimageview

i am new in iOS dev., i'm trying to display the cover photo of Facebook in an uiimageview. i already read the Facebook Graph API but couldn't get it done.

Is there any site that clearly explains or gives an example on how to get and display the cover photo of fb in ion uiimageview.

i want to display this:

[image]

this is from Facebook Graph API Explorer